# Saving a screenshot of a custom view on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-canvas, screenshot

I'm trying to save a screenshot of my current Activity, but not the whole view, just part of it.
In my case:
[My activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7srHe.png)

At the attached image, i want to save a bitmap constructed from views B,C & D.

B is a linear layout, C is a pure bitmap, and D is a relative layout.

To my understanding, one way to go is creating a canvas, add all 'elements' into it and finally have the custom bitmap desired.

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
iViewBHeight= viewB.getHeight();
// Prepare empty bitmap as output
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapC.getWidth(),bitmapC.getHeight() +     iViewBHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
// Flush source image into canvas
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
// Draw bitmap C to canvas 'under' view B
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapC, 0, iViewBHeight, null);
// Draw view B to canvas
viewB.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
viewB.buildDrawingCache(true);
canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(viewB.getDrawingCache()), 0, 0, null);
viewB.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

// Desired bitmap is at 'result'
```

The result is that bitmap C is drawn Ok, but view B is too large and extends the bitmap.
I didn't try adding view D..

Can anyone help me? Maybe there are better ways achieving my goal?
Thanks!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/5202007

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11188635/5202007

Comment: Thank you for your comment Tauqir, the first link solution takes a screenshot of the whole screen which i don't need. The seconds one doesn't work for me.

Comment: please post your xml for screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to accomplish that is to grab a screenshot of the `Activity`'s entire content, then crop off the A `View`. The `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap bmp, Rect src, Rect dest, Paint pnt)` overload does this easily. The `Rect src` describes section of the source `Bitmap` you're copying, while `dest` is the section of the destination `Bitmap` that the source will be drawn in. (NB: the `Rect`s don't have to be the same size.)

I believe the following method should do what you want, if I'm following you correctly.

```
private Bitmap capture()
{
    View actContent = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(actContent.getWidth(),
                                        actContent.getHeight() - viewA.getHeight(),
                                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

    actContent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Rect src = new Rect(0, viewA.getHeight(), actContent.getWidth(), actContent.getHeight());
    Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, result.getWidth(), result.getHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(actContent.getDrawingCache(), src, dest, null);
    actContent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, Its exactly what i was looking for.
I didn't know it is possible to do that!
Thank you Mike!